# Alfresco Community v.5 Cluster High Availability?

Tags: alfresco

The documentation is a bit confusing. It is possible to mount a high availability system with load balancing with the community version of Alfresco 5.2

I read in the official documentation that apparently it can be possible, but then I read about Hazelcast and that it would only be for the enterprise version. So can you or can't you? What requirements do you have?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Alfresco CE > 4.2 there is no support for clustering and load balancing of Alfresco. However, I know of two (private) projects where Alfresco CE was clustered. Clustering means that the cache is synchronized on multiple servers and a central database and file store is used. However, if you cluster Alfresco, you would actually have to cluster filesystem and database as well, which becomes problematic (at least for the DB).

Theoretically, it would also be possible to disable the cache, but that would have massive performance implications.
However, I am not a big fan of Alfresco clustering (purely personal opinion) as availability does not increase with complexity and scalability is only improved for certain scenarios.